# Is there any way to remove float values (both left and right) from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The job table has a column Named 'Render Time' that contains total-render-time for projects. However, this column 'Render Time' is in Data Type 'text' but the data that I get from another program comes in Day/time format. So, is there any way to re-format the 'Render Time'column while retaining the current data?

| Job ID | Render Time |
| --- | --- |
| 119 | 1.10:22:34.43 |
| 120 | 2.12:40:12.00 |

1.10:22:34.43 -> 1(Day).10(hour):22(minutes):34(second).43(milliseconds)

Need to convert this into -> 10:22:34

Any solution using PSQL or python?

I tried converting column type into Time in PSQL but it didn't work, also tried python using pandas it worked somewhat but the result wasn't the one I needed.

Comment: Just a minor note, 430 milliseconds.

Comment: `substr(render_time,3,8)`?

Comment: `SPLIT_PART(render_time, '.', 2)` would do the trick

Comment: Those aren't "float values".

Comment: Btw: such duration should be stored in a column with the data type `interval `